# What is this called in google workspace add-ins?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I would like to add custom actions on this menu in my project. But cannot find any documentation on how this is accessible.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are looking for [Universal actions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/universal-actions)

- Those are being specified in the [Addon manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/workspace-manifests)
- The Universal actions contain `labels` (the menu entries you see in the three-dot menu) and are tied to either an `openLink` or `runFunction` action - depending on your intention

Sample manifest from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/universal-actions#example):

```js
 "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata"
  ],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Universal Actions Only Addon",
      "logoUrl": "https://www.example.com/hosted/images/2x/my-icon.png",
      "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
        "https://www.google.com",
        "https://www.example.com/urlbase"
      ],
      "universalActions": [{
          "label": "Open google.com",
          "openLink": "https://www.google.com"
        }, {
          "label": "Open contact URL",
          "runFunction": "openContactURL"
        }, {
          "label": "Open settings",
          "runFunction": "createSettingsResponse"
        }, {
          "label": "Run background sync",
          "runFunction": "runBackgroundSync"
      }],
      ...
    },
    "gmail": {
      "contextualTriggers": [
        {
          "unconditional": {},
          "onTriggerFunction": "getContextualAddOn"
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
```